# How to close evince Document Viewer (PDF)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, ux

Usability problem, End User perspective:

Having opened an PDF in **evince** Document Viewer (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), how to close via UI?

- there is no close button.
- even if you go fullscreen by pressing F11, the menu at right top does not have a "close" function, nor the top menu
- ESC doesn't do the job (which would be the most expected way)
- Q doesn't work either
- nor does CTRL-Q, Shift-Q, CTRL-Shift-Q
- nor F4 or Alt-F4

That's all the key combinations people are used to for closing a window or program.

So, what can I tell the average end-user about this? Guiding them through opening a shell, identifying the process and killing it doesn't instill confidence in ease of use of Ubuntu as a desktop.

[image: screenshot of the viewer, contents removed]

Comment: have you tried Ctrl + W? please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1373844/edit) your question to include the name of the program

Comment: For most users, there IS a close button. For example, boot your old 20.04 LiveUSB and enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment, and download and open a PDF. I just did, and there is a close button. Have you made any changes to your desktop? Any add-ons? Extensions? Theme changes? If so, please detail those in your question above.

Comment: at terminal killall -9 evince. and you could do a keyboard shortcut for it, though this will kill all instances of evince if you have other documents opened. evinced got killed at the same time. confidence? hahahhahahaha. experience.

Comment: @user535733 that user I'm talking about hasn't made changes for lack of knowledge. Some PDF show as expected, but some go in a type of non-fullscreen, yet lacking the close button mode. Not sure what the criterion is (open policy flags in PDF?).

Comment: @foo, I see. **Either you have found a bug or something is modified** in the system, even if you don't think so: What Document viewer (program name and version)? Can you upload and/or link to a pdf file that makes the document viewer behave like that?

Comment: @sudodus: program is evince, screenshot added; the document where this happens does contain personal data of that user. I can try and find document properties on a different machine though.

Answer (score 4):

In my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS the Document Viewer alias `evince` can be closed

- with the **<kbd>x</kbd>** button at the top right corner of the window or
- with the **<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>** keys (sometimes <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) or
- with the **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>** keys (thanks @totalynotanoob)
  or
- via a pop-up menu when right-clicking on the title bar.

[image]

Comment: The point being this expected icon is *not shown*. Hence the question.

Comment: Right-click on the title bar however worked, so I accept this as the solution.

Comment: @foo, So you have not really solved the problem. Were you able to find a pdf file, that causes this problem, and at the same time is possible to publish (or maybe send to me privately)?

Comment: @foo, I just came across [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629254/minimize-maximize-close-icons-not-showing-in-gnome) that might be helpful for you: reinstalling gnome-shell and updating might be a quick fix. There are also other suggestions.

Comment: Thank you! This issue pertains to a specific set of PDF files only, so I assume it's something about the PDF permission flags and how they are handled in evince; but above link may come in handy another time.